# How to create LVM based nodes in MAAS 1.8

Tags: maas

It was a suprise that debian-installer deployment method is missing from WebGUI, however MAAS cli/API has got it as a new option.

Furthermore I realized this feature is depricated according to notes in sources:

```
    :param boot_type: The installation type of the node. 'fastpath': use
        the default installer. 'di' use the debian installer.
        Note that using 'di' is now deprecated and will be removed in favor
        of the default installer in MAAS 1.9.
```

I would like to manage some nodes where LVM is needed. It can be achieved using debian-installer. Is there any way to deploy LVM based partitioning using fastpath?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the preseed option is still there.  The default is:

```
d-i     partman/early_command string debconf-set partman-auto/disk `list-devices disk | head -n1`
d-i     partman-iscsi/mainmenu string finish
d-i     partman-auto/method string regular
d-i     partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i     partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i     partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i     partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i     partman/choose_partition        select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i     partman/confirm boolean true
d-i     partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i     partman/default_filesystem string ext4
```

You should be able to tweak this as needed.

Comment: I'll also reference:  https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/storage.html#storage - storage is vastly improved in 1.9